# How to modify a query?

Tags: wordpress

I need to modify the query on single page to show the post with post_status publish and future (Default not showing post with future post status).
Here is my code but not working

```
query_posts($query_string . '&post_status=publish,future');
```

Comment: What exactly is happening with the code you show?

Comment: My code still not showing future article, just article with post status publish

Comment: I tested the same code you posted here, and appears in the returned list the Posts with status "future" too. Maybe is another part of your code that affect your result.

Answer (score 0):

For getting both the post, you need to use following code for post_status

$args = array('post_status' =>array('future','published'));
query_posts($args);